# Ajax call not reaching controller method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Yes, there are a whole bunch of posts with similar questions. I've tried to follow the answers in them, but my ajax call still isn't reaching the controller method.

controller (SalesController.cs):

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult fillVarietiesSelect(int species_id)
{
    String[] alist = {"a","b","c"};
    return Json(alist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

javascript:

```
$('#species-select').on('change', function () {
    var species_id = $('#species-select').val();
    console.log("species id selected " + species_id);
    alert("species id selected " + species_id);
    $('#variety-select').empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("fillVarietiesSelect", "Sales")',
        data: {species_id : species_id},
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});
```

The on change event is firing, and the alert pops up with the correct data. I have a breakpoint set at the controller method, but execution doesn't seem to get there.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console or request network tab?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC throws so many console errors!  But the last is: `Empty string passed to getElementById(). jquery-1.10.2.js:188:0
GET  XHR http://localhost:65244/@Url.Action(%22fillVarietiesSelect%22,%20%22Sales%22)`

Comment: The network panel is showing a 404 error for `GET @Url.Action("fillVarietiesSelect", "Sales")`

Comment: If you make you controller action method return string then it works file. The problem is coming when you return json. try returning list<string> instead of json

Comment: Try changing HttpGet to HttpPost in Controller method. Also, change ajax type from type: 'GET' to type:'POST'.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh OP wants GET.

Comment: I'm happy to use either get or post, but ultimately I want a structure with the fields in an object. I can't see any other way of doing this except with JSON. I'm trying to bring in data to dynamically fill a select list, such as http://plnkr.co/edit/91FYs44DuLkS19YPLzd6?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing exactly like following

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult receive2(string p)
    {
        ViewBag.name = p;
        List<string> lst = new List<string>() { p };
        return Json(lst,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Client side

```
      $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Main/receive2", // the method we are calling
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { "p": $("#txtname").val() },
             dataType:"json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("yes");
                alert('Yay! It worked!tim' + result);
                window.location = "http://google.com";
                // Or if you are returning something

            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('Oh no aa :(' + result[0]);
            }

        });
```

I have checked it's working

Comment: That did it. I think the problem may have been trying to call the val an int instead of a string, and trying to send it as an int.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, changing the parameter from `int` to `string` resolved the problem.

On the server side I had,

> public string RemoveByDocumentID(int DocumentID)

changing that to

> public string RemoveByDocumentID(string DocumentID)

resolved the issue.

On the same context, I have another method in the same name (overloaded method). Which was also contributing to the issue, so I made the method name unique.

Answer (score 0):

Your 404 error is telling you that @Url.Action is not being parsed by the view engine. The @ is Razor syntax, so for this to work you need to be using a .cshtml extension for C# views or .vbhtml for VB views and be using MVC 3 or above.

Comment: The view is `index.cshtml`.